# Установка emmet в sublime

Tags: emmet, sublime-text

После установки emmet в sublime перестал разворачиваться html, что делать?

Comment: @4knort, какая версия sublime? 2 или 3?  
Вы, случаем, не забыли установить синтаксис для файла, если у него не одно из поддерживаемых Emmet расширений?  
Попробуйте создать новый файл, выбрать `View->Syntax->HTML` и проверить работу плагина.

Comment: @4knort, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Уже был такой вопрос, и решением было удалить emmet через package control, а затем вновь его поставить